# Webpack compilation failed in react-native-web on {Node} i.e. Flow Syntax saying "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: react-native, webpack, flowtype, babel-loader, react-native-web

I am new to `node/npm`, `react` and `react-native` so very new to `react-native-web` as well. It's been 3 days for me to integrate `react-native-web` in a *Hello World App* generated using `npx react-native init` [as per the doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). I tried using both templates: with and without typescript, but no success so far. The farthest I got is to run the app code written in `index.web.js` but if I add any component from `./src/components/` then I get errors, mostly of **webpack**.

---

I created a test repo for easy regeneration of error, So **Steps to reproduce** are as below:

1. Download [this repo](https://github.com/ShivamS136/react-native-web-metro-error-flow) in your system.
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run web`

Now you'll see the error in the terminal.

***Versions:***

- metro-react-native-babel-preset: 0.66.0
- node: 16.3.0
- npm: 7.8.0
- OS: Windows 10 - 64 bit

---

I followed official documentation but with `webpack@^4` and referred [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-web-complete-tutorial/) and  somehow managed to reach the below situation:

- Webpage is getting rendered if my whole code is inside `index.web.js`.
- But when I import `App` inside this then I get compilation failed due to loader error.

**Working `index.web.js`:**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

class ReactNativeWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#142a3d',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeWeb', () => ReactNativeWeb);
AppRegistry.runApplication('ReactNativeWeb', {
  rootTag: document.getElementById('react-native-web-app'),
});
```

**New Errorful `index.web.js`:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/components/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

AppRegistry.runApplication(appName, {
  rootTag: document.getElementById('react-native-web-app'),
});
```

**src/components/App.jsx**

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
// import {Node} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const Section = ({children, title}) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your Changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Now I get the below errors, Seems related to webpack loaders associated with babel or flow:

```sh
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen/components/DebugInstructions.js 11:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
|
> import type {Node} from 'react';
| import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
| import React from 'react';
 @ ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen/index.js 17:0-63 20:0-27:2
 @ ./src/components/App.jsx
 @ ./index.web.js
 @ multi ./index.web.js
```

My all set up files are as below:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "awesomeproject2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.16.5",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native-web"
  }
}
```

**web/webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.
// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// `node_module`.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /(\.js)|(\.jsx)$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),
  ],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      //   cacheDirectory: true,
      // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: [
        'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
      ],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: ['react-native-web'],
    },
  },
};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    // load any web API polyfills
    // path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),
    // your web-specific entry file
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),
  ],

  // configures where the build ends up
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.web.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
  },

  // ...the rest of your config

  module: {
    rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration],
  },

  resolve: {
    // This will only alias the exact import "react-native"
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
    // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
    // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
    // `.web.js`.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.web.jsx'],
  },
};
```

**.bashrc**

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**.flowconfig** (Added part below `[options]` only)

```sh
# Alias the package name
module.name_mapper='^react-native$' -> 'react-native-web'

# Point flow to the 'module' field by default
module.system.node.main_field=module
module.system.node.main_field=main
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It's been resolved, my *Hello World* is done.

These 2 replies from the maintainer himself (@necolas) on [this discussion](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/discussions/2052) helped me to get the issue.

> ***Reply 1 by @necolas***
> This line in the stack trace is telling you that you're trying to bundle RN internal code in your web bundle: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen/index.js.
>
> First, you should not be loading any of the RN package on web, especially not parts that aren't part of the public API . Second, as mentioned in the inline comments of the config you pasted above, you need to explicitly list everything in node_modules that needs compiling.

> ***Reply 2 by @necolas***
>
> ```js
> import {
>   Colors,
>   DebugInstructions,
>   Header,
>   LearnMoreLinks,
>   ReloadInstructions,
> } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
> ```
>
> All this code of the problem. You should not import from Libraries. This is not part of the public API. And you need to actually read the webpack code comments and follow the instructions when importing code from node_modules.

So I removed importing components from `'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen'` and that's it. More detail is in [this commit](https://github.com/ShivamS136/react-native-web-metro-error-flow/commit/002aab5d72152901dac77d4ae88de84b24317cf7).

I added [an article for setting up React Native for Web from Scratch](https://dev.to/shivams136/create-react-native-app-for-android-ios-and-web-without-expo-48lc).